# How to connect raw html <a href> tag to React javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I building out a small web app that simulates browsing WikiPedia by pulling raw html WikiPedia article content (via it's api). I'm then displaying the html in my app by using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML".

I trying to figure out how to allow a user to click on a an unmounted  < ahref="wiki/javascript" > tag and capture that event on the React side. I wanted to capture that   tag click to update UI state and make server requests.

When using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" click events are not recognized by react. So I added a function on the global window object on the React side to be clicked on by the  tags but get a warning about 'unmounted components' and 'memory leaks'.

How can I prevent the raw unmounted   tags from reloading the page and capture that click event in order to update my React's UI?

Comment: Posting the relevant code you have already along with the question is definitely going to help. Nonetheless it seems that you are looking for a <Link> react tag

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a better way to do what you're trying to do, but with your current implementation:

You can grab a ref on the node that you're doing dangerouslySetInnerHTML, add a click event listener, use event bubbling to capture that link event and finally invoke `preventDefault()`.

```
class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
      if(this.myRef){
        this.myRef.addEventListener('click', this.anchorLinkListener);
      }
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
      if(this.myRef){
         this.myRef.removeEventListener('click', this.anchorLinkListener)
      }
    }

    anchorLinkListener = (e) => {
       if(e.target.tagName === 'A') {
          console.log('Anchor link clicked')
          e.preventDefault();
       }
    }

    render(){
      return (
        <div 
          ref={(ref) => {this.myRef = ref}}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">click me</a>'}}
        />
      )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am kind of looking at the problem from another angle.

I am thinking "hmm, *dangerouslySetInnerHTML* sounds rather ominous, as if I probably shouldn't use it. I wonder if there are nicer, safer alternatives...".

After doing a quick google search for "alternative to dangerouslySetInnerHTML" one of the promising results is [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@remarkablemark/an-alternative-to-dangerously-set-innerhtml-64a12a7c1f96).

TLDR; we can do cool things with packages like [HTML React Parser](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser) and that may solve our problem of not being able to capture events properly.

If we have access to the `event` object once again, we should be able to read its attributes and do whatever else we need to do